# How to Open or display 10GB file in Java

Tags: java

The EmEditor claims https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/large-file-support/files-up-to-248gb/ it can open upto 248gb of text file

I have 1GB or 10GB text - i.e log file

How to show up via Java in Java Swing UI or any UI with search option to search a text?

Thanks

Comment: This might be a little broad for SO. Do you know how to read files in general?

Comment: Yes, i know..but which UI standalone will support such a huge string..a lazy loading or how to process it like EmEditor

Comment: I want to build something like EmEditor in java

Comment: As @Thomas stated, this question is very general. You cannot (and also EmEditor doesn't) read 248GB in memory. You do partial loading with loading areas (mappings) of the file. Are you looking for read-only or also writes? Are you familiar with file-handling in Java? Maybe this is a good starting point: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/nio/memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer/

Comment: read-only...if loading 248gb is not possible then how does EmEditor able to do the same on the screen....Is this a limitation in java?

Comment: This is not a limitation of Java but a general one. Note the "in memory" part. As an example if your machine has 32GB of memory you can't load a 248GB file into it. You'd need to only read chunks and search those or use something like memory mapped files or streaming.

Comment: The fact that many editors don't support such large files should already indicate it's not an easy task.

Comment: You don't have to load the entire file into memory,  Consider loading chunks, typically, current, page, prior page and next page.  You can also do first and last page depending on what controls you have on the screen.  You just need to keep track of your file pointers and do offsets into the file for reading

Comment: no i tested some editors which is very fast...glogg, EmEditor, Editpad Lite. how to build something similar in java

Comment: How to open files in chunk in java swing?